# Mulesoft batch crashes

Tags: batch-processing, mulesoft

I am new to mulesoft, have a question regarding batch processing.if batch process crashed in between and some record already processed, what happened when batch processing start again. Duplicate data ???

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends upon a few things. First, unless you configure the batch job scope to allow record level failures, the entire job will stop when a record fails. Second, if you do configure to allow failures, then the batch will continue to process all records. In such a case, each batch step can be configured to accept only successful records (the default), or only failed records, or all records.

So the answer to your question is dependent upon configuration.

And as far as duplicate data, this part is entirely up to you.

If you have the job stop for failure, when you restart it, the set of records you provide at that time will be the ones processed. If you submit records that have been processed once before, then they will be processed again. You can provide for filtering either upon reentry to the batch job, or as the records are successfully processed.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question I would like to know couple of things.
a. what do u mean by batch crashes ?
are you saying during the batch processing there is some JVM hit and the
batch started again ?

or There is failure during processing of some records the batch?

a.1 --> if there is JVM hit then then the entire program halts.
need to restart the programme. which results into processing
the same set of record.

a.2 --> To handle the failure record inside batch.
In the batch step you can do three steps as below .

1. set the batch job to continue irrespective of any error

   ```
           <batch:job jobName="Batch1" maxFailedRecords="-1">
   ```
2. In the batch job  create 3 batch step :-

   ```
         a.processRecord.- process the 1st record in batch 
           queue.

         b.ProcessSuccessful-
           if there is no exception in a. go to batch step b.

         c.processFailure record.- 
           if there is exception in a. goto batch step. c
   ```

THE ENTIRE SAMPLE CODE IS SHOWN BELOW .

```
<batch:job jobName="batchJob" maxFailedRecords="-1" >
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="processRecord"  acceptPolicy="ALL" >

            log.info("process any record COMES IN THE STEP");

        </batch:step>

        <batch:step name="ProcessSuccessful"
            acceptPolicy="NO_FAILURES">

            log.info("process only SUCCESSFUL record")

        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="processFailure" 
           acceptPolicy="ONLY_FAILURES">

            log.info("process only FAILURE record");

        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
   <batch:on-complete>

     log.info("on complete  phase , log the successful and 
     failure count");

  </batch:on-complete>
 </batch:job>
```

N.B --> the code as per Mule 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

It will try to continue processing the pending data in the batch queues, unless it was corrupted by the crash.